# Django filter - filter by Avg of a field in related model

Tags: python, django

I'm using django-filter to filter through my `Festival` model. There is another model, `Review`, which contains reviews about festivals and related to the `Festival` model by a `Foreignkey`.
My goal is to be able to filter festivals by `friendly` average > 3 (`friendly` is a one field for example in `Review` model).

Any idea how to do it? Many thanks =]

**Models.py**

```
class Review(models.Model):
...
festival = models.ForeignKey(
    Festival,
    related_name='Festival_Reviews',
    on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    null=True,
    blank = True,
    default = '',
)
score_choices = (
    (1, 'Bad'),
    (2, 'Okay'),
    (3, 'Good'),
    (4, 'Great'),
    (5, 'Superb'),
)


friendly = models.IntegerField(
    choices=score_choices,
    default='',
    null=True,
    blank = True,
)

class Festival(models.Model):
...
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

**Filter.py** (this was my idea, I'm pretty new to Django)

```
class FestivalFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    ...
    Festival_Reviews_friendly = django_filters.BooleanFilter(field_name='Festival_Reviews',method='avg_above3')

    def avg_above3(self, queryset, name, value):
        return queryset.aggregate(friendly_avg=Avg('friendly')).filter(friendly_avg__gt=3)
```

**Views.py**

```
class HomePage(ListFilteredMixin, AjaxListView):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    page_template = 'index_page.html'
    model = models.Festival
    paginate_by = 12
    context_object_name = 'festivals'
    filter_set = FestivalFilter
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it like this:

```
class FestivalFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    festival_friendly_review = django_filters.BooleanFilter(field_name='Festival_Reviews',method='avg_above3')
    class Meta:
       model = Festival
       fields = ['festival_friendly_review']

    def avg_above3(self, queryset, name, value):
            return queryset.annotate(friendly_avg=Avg('Festival_Reviews__friendly')).filter(friendly_avg__gt=3)  # use annotate instead of aggregate
```

#### Usage:

```
 filter = FestivalFilter({festival_friendly_review:True}, Festival.objects.all())
 print(filter.qs)
 print(filter.qs.values('friendly_avg'))
```

Comment: Thanks :) it doesn't work either, anyway I think it must be something more profound that has to do with django filter

Comment: @OrPreiss please see my updated answer. Also if you face further issue, please share what problem you are facing. Thanks

Comment: Thanks again, now it returns this error: FieldError at /
Cannot resolve keyword 'friendly' into field. Choices are: ....((all Festival model fields))....

Comment: Great many thanks, I accepted the answer :)
Now I have many fields I would like to filter according to (like friendly, good for famlieis etc.. ) and I want to use the same avg_above3 function to calculate the avg > 3 (currently this funciton is made specifically for friendly) , any idea how I can go on that?

Comment: you can add new filter just like `festival_friendly_review` and use it like this: `filter = FestivalFilter({festival_friendly_review:True, family_friendly:True}, Festival.objects.all())`.(If I understood you correctly)